# Two-qubit Bell measurement matrix where the two qubits are not contiguouis

Tags: mathematics, textbook-and-exercises, linear-algebra, bell-basis

In the answer [here](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/23310/transformation-matrix-for-a-two-qubit-operation-where-there-are-more-than-two-qu), it is explained that where the measurement operates on only a subset of the qubits of the system (for example qubits 2 and 3 out of five), the matrix can be constructed using the Kronecker product. However, I need to perform the measurement on qubits 1 and 4. So it is not clear to me what matrices to put into the Kronecker product.

The particular measurement I need to do is the Bell measurement, whose matrix is
$$\begin{bmatrix}
0&1&1&0\\
0&-1&1&0\\
1&0&0&1\\
1&0&0&-1
\end{bmatrix}.$$

Comment: Use swap gates to temporarily turn it into the case you know how to do.

Comment: How do you construct the matrix for swapping, for example, qubits 1 and 3 out of five, so as to get a contiguous pair?

Comment: You can build a swap of non-adjacent qubits by composing swaps of adjacent qubits. For example, to swap qubit 1 with 3 (and leave all other qubits unaffected), swap qubit 1 with 2, then swap 2 with 3 and finally 1 with 2 again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Explicit indices

The difficulty here arises from making indices implicit in tensor product expressions. For example, the unitary $U$ corresponding to controlled-NOT gate on qubits $1$ and $2$ and identity on qubit $3$ is often written down as

$$
U=\text{CNOT}\otimes I\tag1
$$

but a similar unitary $U'$ corresponding to controlled-NOT on qubits $1$ and $3$ and identity on qubit $2$ cannot be written this way

$$
U'=\text{???}.\tag2
$$

A solution is to introduce subscripts that identify the qubits

$$
U_{123}=\text{CNOT}_{12}\otimes I_3\tag{1'}
$$

which allows us to write $(2)$ as

$$
U_{123}'=\text{CNOT}_{13}\otimes I_2.\tag{2'}
$$

### Computing matrix elements of tensor products

The additional advantage of this more explicit notation is that it provides a simple algorithm for computing matrix elements of tensor products. To that end replace qubit list like $123$ with two lists of indices like $i_1i_2i_3;k_1k_2k_3$ where $i_m$ are row indices and $k_m$ are column indices and where $m\in\{1,2,3\}$ identifies a qubit corresponding to each index. Then $(2)$ becomes

$$
U_{i_1i_2i_3;k_1k_2k_3}=\text{CNOT}_{i_1i_2;k_1k_2}I_{i_3;k_3}\tag3
$$

and $(2')$ becomes

$$
U_{i_1i_2i_3;k_1k_2k_3}'=\text{CNOT}_{i_1i_3;k_1k_3}I_{i_2;k_2}.\tag{3'}
$$

If we now interpret $i_1i_2i_3\in\{000,001,\dots,111\}$ as the binary encoding of the row number of the matrix on the LHS and $k_1k_2k_3$ as the binary encoding of the column number, then $(3)$ and $(3')$ give us simple direct formulas for computing matrix elements of $U$ and $U'$ from the matrix elements of the factor matrices $\text{CNOT}$ and $I$.

### Example

For example, the matrix of the CNOT gate is

$$
\text{CNOT}=\begin{bmatrix}
1&0&0&0\\
0&1&0&0\\
0&0&0&1\\
0&0&1&0
\end{bmatrix}.\tag4
$$

In other words,

$$
\text{CNOT}_{ij;i'j'}=\begin{cases}
1&\text{ if }i=i'=0\text{ and }j=j',\\
1&\text{ if }i=i'=1\text{ and }j\ne j',\\
0&\text{ otherwise}.
\end{cases}\tag5
$$

Also,

$$
I_{i;j}=\begin{cases}
1\text{ if }i=j,\\
0\text{ if }i\ne j.
\end{cases}\tag6
$$

Substituting $(5)$ and $(6)$ into $(3)$, we get

$$
U_{123} = \text{CNOT}_{12}\otimes I_3 = \begin{bmatrix}
1&&&&&&&\\
&1&&&&&&\\
&&1&&&&&\\
&&&1&&&&\\
&&&&&&1&\\
&&&&&&&1\\
&&&&1&&&\\
&&&&&1&&
\end{bmatrix}\tag7
$$

and substituting $(5)$ and $(6)$ into $(3')$, we get

$$
U_{123}' = \text{CNOT}_{13}\otimes I_2 = \begin{bmatrix}
1&&&&&&&\\
&1&&&&&&\\
&&1&&&&&\\
&&&1&&&&\\
&&&&&1&&\\
&&&&1&&&\\
&&&&&&&1\\
&&&&&&1&
\end{bmatrix}.\tag{7'}
$$

### Kronecker product

Finally, it is not hard to check that the above algorithm recovers the usual definition of the [Kronecker product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product)

$$
A\otimes B=\begin{bmatrix}a_{11}B&\dots&a_{1n}B\\&\dots&\\a_{n1}B&\dots&a_{nn}B\end{bmatrix}\tag8
$$

as a special case since in terms of matrix elements $(4)$ can be written as

$$
(A\otimes B)_{i_1i_2;k_1k_2} = A_{i_1;k_1}B_{i_2;k_2}\tag9
$$

where the compound indices $i_1i_2$ and $k_1k_2$ are to be interpreted as above.

Comment: I can see that this last answer addresses my concern, but I cannot quite grasp it. For example, I cannot quite see how to construct $CNOT_{13}$. It seems it has something to do with the indices and a generalization of the Kronecker product. Perhaps I adapt the formula for the product so that different indices come into play somehow?

Comment: $\text{CNOT}_{12}$ and $\text{CNOT}_{13}$ have the same matrix, but different index labels. Consequently, $U_{123}=\text{CNOT}_{12}\otimes I_3$ will be different than $U_{123}'=\text{CNOT}_{13}\otimes I_2$. I have added an example that demonstrates this.

Comment: I was able to construct $U^\prime_{123}$ per this recipe, but I am still wondering about the meaning of $CNOT_{123}$ since it doesn't exactly refer to a circuit with CNOT on qubits 1 and 3 and identity on qubit 2

Comment: CNOT should have only two subscripts for identifying qubits, e.g. $\text{CNOT}_{13}$, not three as in $\text{CNOT}_{123}$ (since it's a two-qubit gate!). It can also be written with four index subscripts like $\text{CNOT}_{ij;kl}$ when we wish to separately name the row and column index for each qubit (a fancy way of saying this is that CNOT is an order four tensor).